# change android search interface behavior like google search app

Tags: android

i want my search interface like the google search app :

i can not upload images so i pasted links to them

starting interface can be made like [this](http://tinypic.com/r/25zm1rk/8)

and when some one clicks/touches the input box this happens:

**input box does not change and the keyboard dialog pops up in google search app**

but in my app the text input box changes and after that the keyboard pops why is that ?

[here](http://tinypic.com/r/9aa0y1/8) is the comparsion

how one make search interface like the google search app ?

Comment: set focusable to FALSE for your EditText.

Comment: @SunitKumarGupta set focusable it doesn't worked out